# problem with activity crashing when a function is called

Tags: android, methods, android-intent

this is my first time on this forum, so forgive me if my question seems odd. I'll try to be as thorough as possible.
I am creating a translation program.
this program has a menu activity, translate activity, addword activity.
The three activities are linked together via intents and they are 
added in the manifest file.
In the translate activity I want to create a method for translating.
After I press the translate button, the program crashes.

```
public class VertaalActivity extends Activity {
private Button vertaal;
private Button terug;
private EditText ET_NL;
private EditText ET_EN;
private ArrayList<String>nlWoorden = new ArrayList<String>();
private ArrayList<String>enWoorden = new ArrayList<String>();

public void Vertaal(){

    String woord = ET_NL.getText().toString();

        if(nlWoorden.contains(woord)){
            int i = nlWoorden.indexOf(woord);
            ET_EN.setText(enWoorden.get(i));
        }else{
            ET_EN.setText("Woord niet gevonden");
        }

}

public void ArrayVullen(){
    nlWoorden.add("auto");
    nlWoorden.add("bord");
    nlWoorden.add("trein");
    nlWoorden.add("spel");
    nlWoorden.add("scherm");
    nlWoorden.add("toetsenbord");
    nlWoorden.add("foto");
    enWoorden.add("car");
    enWoorden.add("plate");
    enWoorden.add("train");
    enWoorden.add("game");
    enWoorden.add("screen");
    enWoorden.add("keyboard");
    enWoorden.add("picture");
}

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.vertalerlayout);
    terug = (Button)findViewById(R.id.terug);
    vertaal = (Button)findViewById(R.id.vertalen);

    ArrayVullen();

    vertaal.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            Vertaal();

            /*
             * Tested the toast and the toast shows the text 
             * 
            Context context = getApplicationContext();
            CharSequence text = "Hello toast!";
            int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
            toast.show();
            */
        }

    });

    terug.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(VertaalActivity.this,MenuActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });

}
```

}

Comment: Can you post the error message in LogCat when this happens?

Comment: Can you also please post the manifest file?

Comment: Not sure but should that just be?:
Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(),MenuActivity.class);

Comment: I'll change that tonight and see what happens. So far the code works so thx for al the help. Will also post the manifest file. It is still work in progress and I think I will need to edit the manifest file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see that you get the EditTexts from your XML (like you do with the buttons). Before using ET_NL you need to do something like this:

```
ET_NL = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etnl); // Or whatever id you've declared in your layout XML
```

Same thing goes for the ET_EN variable. Otherwise the will be null in your Vertaal() method, causing the app to crash.

Comment: ok thx for the reply. Silly mistake on my part. Will try this.

Comment: We all make silly mistakes every now and then. Please make sure to accept the answer if it helps you solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code before using the editText field

```
ET_NL= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext1);
ET_EN = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext2);
```